# How to find the most basic materials in a crafting recipe (python)?

Tags: python

so I have been searching the web to try and help with the issue above but I can't seem to find a source to help me complete the project.

Essentially, I want to take an item I specify (such as a **bed**), and for the code to find the most basic materials needed to craft the item.  A **bed** requires 3 **wool** and 3 **planks**.  Each **wool** requires 4 **string** (a basic material), and each 4 **planks** can be crafted from 1 **wood**(the other basic material).  As such the code would return:

**12 string** and **1 wood** required to craft.

I thought I could make classes to organize the items, but found that I could not access the recipe list from the other classes:

```
class bed:

    class wool:
        id=1
        def getId(self):
            print(self.id)
        name="wool"
        def getName(self):
            print(self.name)
        recipe= [{"amt":4,"items":"string"}]
        def getRecipe(self):
            print(str(self.recipe[0]["amt"])+" of "+str(self.recipe[0]["items"]))
```

Something like this for every item.  I know I need to make object to actually use any of this, but I wouldn't know how to trace back the recipe to keep going back until I reach the absolute basic material.

I also tried to make a mini dictionary:

```
items=[{"uid":0,"name":"bed","recipe":}]
```

but had problems trying to figure out how I was to say 3 wood *and* 3 planks.  Then comes the problem of returning to try and find the most basic material again.

I am new-ish to python/code in general, and I have been teaching myself by doing random projects that pop into my mind, so sorry if my methods or logic seems strange.  Any help will be appreciated!

*Edit: sorry for previous lack of indentation, this is my first post*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Here, you're asking for individual design support, which is outside the Stack Overflow charter.

Comment: Wow... indentation is really off, can you please indent it rightly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or for another take on a solution, you start with a dictionary that
defines your recipes:

```
import math

recipes = {
    'bed': (
        ('wool', 3),
        ('plank', 3),
    ),
    'wool': (
        ('string', 4),
    ),
    'plank': (
        ('wood', 0.25),
    ),
    'wood': (),
    'string': (),
}
```

And then use a recursive function to resolve an item into its
constituent components:

```
def _resolve(thing, count=1):
    recipe = []

    if not recipes[thing]:
        recipe.append((thing, count))
    else:
        for comp, req in recipes[thing]:
            recipe.extend(_resolve(comp, req*count))

    return recipe


def resolve(thing):
    '''This is a convenience function that takes carea of rounding
    up fractional amounts to integer values (so if your recipe
    only takes 0.75 wood, this will transform that to 1 wood,
    because you can't use fractional amounts of things).'''
    return [(item, int(math.ceil(count)))
            for item, count in _resolve(thing, 1)]
```

The function behaves like this:

```
>>> resolve('string')
[('string', 1)]
>>> resolve('wood')
[('wood', 1)]
>>> resolve('plank')
[('wood', 1)]
>>> resolve('wool')
[('string', 4)]
>>> resolve('bed')
[('string', 12), ('wood', 1)]
```

Printing things:

```
>>> for item, count in resolve('bed'):
...     print('{} = {}'.format(item, count))
...
string = 12
wood = 1
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I feel like I have a few stupid questions to ask.
1) How would one get the logic of the code to print? (I.e bed = 12 string & 1 wood)?
2)Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't this code essentially go down the list of ALL items in the recipes list?
3)Isn't recursion notoriously slow?  Essentially if I was to expand this list to the total list of items in a game, would this code actually be inefficient (I could just be wrong and I am fully willing to accept that if this is the case)?

Comment: (1) The function returns a list of tuples...just iterate through the list, formatting things as desired. I've added an example. (2) I'm not sure what you mean. This only looks at items in the recipes list that are involved in crafting the item you originally asked about. (3) the best way to answer performance questions is to test it. Recursion can be a perfectly fine solution, and it certainly lends itself to elegant code on occasion. As with any recursive solution, you could re-implement the logic iteratively at the expense of some code complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A good start to this might be to subclass from a very basic item class and keep the other classes pretty bare. Here is a prototype to what you may be thinking:

```
class Item():
    def __init__(self):
        self.RECIPE = {}

    def get_complete_recipe(self):
        if not self.RECIPE:
            return

        print '\nA {} requires:'.format(self)
        for item, count in self.RECIPE.iteritems():
            print '[ {} {} ] '.format(count, item),
            item.get_complete_recipe()

class String(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.RECIPE = {}

    def __str__(cls):
        return 'String'

class Wool(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.RECIPE = {String(): 4}

    def __str__(cls):
        return 'Wool'

class Wood(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.RECIPE = {}

    def __str__(cls):
        return 'Wood'

class Plank(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.RECIPE = {Wood(): .25}

    def __str__(cls):
        return 'Plank'

class Bed(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        self.RECIPE = {Wool(): 3, Plank(): 3}

    def __repr__(cls):
        return 'Bed'


b = Bed()

b.get_complete_recipe()
```

We are able to get the complete recipe of any item this way. `__str__` lets us print out the actual name of the class to our liking. Here you can see that when we get the full recipe of the bed, it breaks down like this:

```
A Bed requires:
[ 3 Wool ]  
A Wool requires:
[ 4 String ]  [ 3 Plank ]  
A Plank requires:
[ 0.25 Wood ]
```

You can add some logic to this, and accumulate the basic materials. This is totally doable as the basic materials have no RECIPE object with items. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I was having trouble with line 10 in the code with:
 for item, count in self.RECIPE.iteritems():
but quickly found out that I could change iteritems to just items.  The only problem I have left is that the recipe for bed does not print.  my output actually comes out to
 A Bed requires:

A Wool requires:
[ 4 String ]  None
[ 3 Wool ]  None

A Plank requires:
[ 0.25 Wood ]  None
[ 3 Plank ]  None

I fail to understand thy the none is printing after all the iterations.  Can I assume that's the code reaching the conclusion that there is no more basic parts to the recipe?

Comment: I believe the problem stems from the get_complete_recipe function.  Since it requires the class to be called upon (I think), it begins to reference itself during the execution

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to have one dictionary for items which are assembled from other items:

```
recipes = {
    "bed": {
        "plank": 3,
        "wool": 3
    },
    "wool": {
        "string": 4
    }
}
```

And have another dictionary for items which break down into other items:

```
yields = {
    "wood": {
        "plank": 4
    }
}
```